# How to read data from an azure database table

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

Hi there I'm trying to read  the users in the table that have a first name of "John".

```
 async private void GetUsers()
        {
            Initialize();
            SyncCoffee();
            try
            {
              await coffeeTable.PullAsync("user", coffeeTable.Where(ct => ct.FirstName == "John" ));
            }

        catch (Exception er)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "the error: "+er, "ok");
        }

    }
```

Initialize method

```
public async Task Initialize()
    {
            var mainPage = new MainPage();
            if (isInitialised)
            {
                return;
            }

            MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("database link");

            const string path = "syncstore.db";

        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<User>();
        await MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

        coffeeTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<User>();
            isInitialised = true;

       }
```

Sync method

```
public async Task SyncCoffee()
        {
            try
            {
                await coffeeTable.PullAsync("allusers", coffeeTable.CreateQuery());
                await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unable to sync coffees, that is alright as we have offline capabilities: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

The error I keep getting is

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help is welcome as I am very new to this.

Comment: Hi @JohnDoe - you can provide more information here. Which line of code is triggering the Null Reference Exception?

Comment: Initialize() and SyncCoffee() are both async, but neither is called using await.  That could present a problem

Comment: @Jason andrew is asking exact point of exception, not function name

Comment: I was making a point to the OP, not answering Andrew's question

Comment: @AndrewShepherd the error seems to be on the line await coffeeTable.PullAsync("user", coffeeTable.Where(ct => ct.FirstName == "John" ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> await coffeeTable.PullAsync("user", coffeeTable.Where(ct => ct.FirstName == "John" ));

Your pull operation for specific users is correct. As Jason commented that you need to await `Initialize()`, `SyncCoffee()` in your `GetUsers` method. The `coffeeTable` object may be `null` and `coffeeTable.PullAsync` would fail before the `Initialize` has been executed. For the similar issue, you could debug via VS and step into your code on your local side to narrow it. Moreover, I recommend you to read adrian hall's book about [An Offline Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#an-offline-client) and [An Online Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#an-online-client).